# How to use a query result to determine a DIV's class?

Tags: php, css

I need to put a result of my query into the 'class="#"' of a 'div' tag.
This will be used to determine the color-scheme for that div.

When users post a message on the website they can select a color-scheme for the display of the message. This is saved in a 5-digit code with the message in the database. I want to retrieve that information on the page where all messages are displayed.

To determine the color-scheme I want to use the query result called: code.

I thought that the following could work:

```
<div id="Wrapper" class="'.$Row['Code'].'">
```

Unfortunately it doesn't, after PHP is parsed, the HTML shows this:

```
<div id="Wrapper" class="/12345/">
```

I would really like to see:

```
<div id="MessagePicture" class="12345">
```

How can I get it to work?
Thanks!

Comment: can you post your php code ? else you could use stripslashes http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Answer (score 0):

If your `$row['Code']` variable contains slashes that you need to get rid of, just use `trim` to get rid of them.

```
<div id="Wrapper" class="'.trim($Row['Code'], '/').'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$Row['Code']` contains something like `/12345/`, you can remove slashes using:

```
$Row['Code'] = trim ($Row['Code'], "/");
```

*(This will remove slashes from the beggining and the end.)*

or:

```
$Row['Code'] = str_replace ("/", "", $Row['Code']);
```

*(This will remove slashes from the whole string.)*